# Arduino Microcontrollers interfacing C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on project and I need to create a program that gets data from an Arduino to determine the status all sensors values. I've researched that the best way to send these data is to send them in one line through the serial port and then parse it in Visual Studio. The problem is I don't know how to parse the said data in order for them to show in different text boxes in the program. Any help would be much appreciated...in one textbox am already showing the data but I want to show all sensors values in different textboxes.

```
namespace Arduino_Data
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort myport;
        private DateTime datetime;
        private string in_data;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

     //   private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      //  {

      //  }

        private void satrt_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myport = new SerialPort();
            myport.BaudRate = 9600;
            myport.PortName = port_name_tb.Text;
            myport.Parity = Parity.None;
            myport.DataBits = 8;
            myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            myport.DataReceived += myport_DataReceived;
            try{
                myport.Open();
                data_tb.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message , "Error");
            }
        }

        void myport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

             in_data = myport.ReadLine();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));





        }

        private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // throw new NotImplementedException();
            datetime = DateTime.Now;
            string time = datetime.Hour + ":" + datetime.Minute + ":" + datetime.Second;
            data_tb.AppendText( time + "\t\t\t"+in_data+"\n");
            int data_value = Convert.ToInt32(in_data);
            pb_value.Value = data_value;
            pb_value.Minimum = 0;
            pb_value.Maximum = 1023;





        }

        private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                myport.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message, "Error");


            }
        }

        private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try { 
            string pathfile = @"C:\Users\irtaz\Desktop\DATA";
            string filename = "arduino_data.txt";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathfile + filename, data_tb.Text);

            MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved to" + pathfile, "Save File");
            }
            catch(Exception ex3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex3.Message, "Error");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any your code ?

Comment: then whole coding file is too large...i want to parse arduino sensors values in separate textboxes.

Comment: //pb for progressbar....and display event shows the data in a text box wich is data_tb...i wnat to show every value in separate textbox.